# Ubuntu 10.10 as guest VMware on Windows7 64-bit - really slow internet - how do I speed it up?

Tags: windows-7, internet, vmware, kubuntu

I may have my terminology wrong here but bear with me:

- Running Kubuntu 10.10 in VMware player on Windows 7 64-bit host
- When I load something on the internet (eg. web browser page load, git pull / push) there is a pregnant pause of at least 5 to 10 seconds, a though the VM is having trouble getting out onto the internet and is performing some sort of lookup. You can clearly see that for example if you load Facebook, it will do the lookup for facebook.com, pause, get it, and then pause again when it does a separate lookup for the cdn the images are hosted on for facebook.

Is there some settings I can play with to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a DNS issue as opposed to a VMWare issue.  The network is obviously working as you can get out to the internet (albeit with delays).

Check what is in /etc/resolv.conf on the guest and ensure that you can reach all the nameserver machines listed in there.

Comment: The VM image was a copy from another machine, which had a particular server IP set in resolv.conf which was slowing things down considerably... thanks for the pointer!